# There is No front Front Controller! in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

as everybody know, Any MVC framework have a frontcontroller, like launch.js in sencha, frontend_dev.php in symfony1, etc..

But as i was going through the book :Angular JS by brad Green, in chapter 7. there it is mentioned that there is no such Main Method, So i doubt then how to handle pre execution functions or pre configuartion/checking. Is there any other ways to handle this.

Comment: why accept an answer that was identical to mine, except it was after mine?

Comment: Dear Mohammad, i did not look at your answer, do not mind, here you go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`app.run()` is what you're looking for, after your module declaration, you can handle any pre-execution configs there.

```
app.run(["$rootScope", ....other dependencies
         function ($rootScope,....) {

}] );
```

Comment: one more doubt, i forgot to ask, IF this acts as front controller, is that means, it will execute when ever page navigats, or does it just runs once?. if i want to check my user authorization/session check on each page navigation

Comment: It runs just once, it's the equivalent of App_Start in asp.net mvc, this runs only the first time your app runs, that means also whenever the page is refreshed, which causes the app to be re-executed, if you want to do something between route changes, look at `$locationChangeStart` and `$routeChangeStart`

Comment: I extended my answer to add an example of what you can do to do something every time there is a change of route. As Mohammad Sepahvand mentioned you have events like `$locationChangeStart` and `$routeChangeStart`.

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you're looking for is the run phase.

In the run phase, all the set up runs, and before of launching any specific controller you can execute configs, add handlers etc.

From the docs:

```
angular.module('myModule', []).
  config(function(injectables) { // provider-injector
    // This is an example of config block.
    // You can have as many of these as you want.
    // You can only inject Providers (not instances)
    // into config blocks.
  }).
  run(function(injectables) { // instance-injector
    // This is an example of a run block.
    // You can have as many of these as you want.
    // You can only inject instances (not Providers)
    // into run blocks
  });
```

You can have a look at in the docs [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module).

This phase runs and adds events according to what you need it for. For example, if you want do do something each time is detected the start of a page change you can do something like:

```
myapp.run(
  function ($rootScope) {

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function () {
      // Do something when the stateChange starts
    });

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {
      // Do something else when the state change is successful.
    });

  }
)
```